# Change user ID for iCloud on iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, password

I am needing to change my apple ID on my iPhone for my iCloud account as it has restored with the incorrect user ID BUT i don't know the password for this user id so it just keeps telling me it's incorrect. What do i do??

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid) to reset your Apple ID password by either email verification or by answering the security questions you set when you created the account.